# Highchart Spider web chart, pointPlacement and tickInterval

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a spider web chart to display the maturity of a specific application.

My question is : How can I remove `pointPlacement` numbers but keep the area (e.g. how the chart displays 0, 1, 2, 3, etc )

also how can I expand the chart without adding more values (e.g. min 0 , max 3, I would like there to be more padding after the 3rd value)

here is the chart : http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/6/

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "more padding after the 3rd value".  Do you want the radial axis lines to extend further or do you want padding before labels (space between "Training" and the chart)?  Also, by pointPlacement, do you mean the axis labels?  The numbers 0,1,2 in your fiddle?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if I wasnt clear, yes I want the radial axis lines to extend further and I do mean the axis labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn off the `yAxis labels`, set `enabled:false` for the `labels`.

```
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels : {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
```

And to give yourself one more point on the axis, get rid of your `min` and `max` setting, or set them to something larger than your largest value.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvhq4jdv/7/